# Apex chart - Radial Chart - How to show label for series with 0 value

Tags: angular, charts, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

In apex chart I am using Radial chart with Multiple type. I need to show the label for series that has value 0. Currently, when I do mouse hover then the label is showing only for value that is >0.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoXZZ.png)

Please refer the code here

https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-radialbar-circle-multiple-s60gi?from-embed=&file=/src/app/app.component.ts

please update the value in chartOptions

series: [44, 55, 67, 83, 0]
labels: ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Berries", "Mango"]

Please can someone help this

I need to show label for all the series.
Also If I mouse hover any where then display the label.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.